# Java JUnit: looking for a "assertNothing"

Tags: java, junit

I am starting with JUnit and try to find the best assert method for a test.

Lets say I have a function to test that

- does not return a value
- throws an exception if input is invalid

e.g.

```
void foo (int a) throws Exception
{
  if (a <= 0)
  { 
     throw new Exception ("below 0");
  }
}
```

I would test a negative input with

```
assertThrows (Exception.class, () -> { foo (-1); });
```

But how can I check if a positive input does NOT throw an exception?

All members I find in Assertion check for a return-value or an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple: just invoke the method:

```
foo(1);
```

If this doesn't throw an exception, there is no exception to cause the test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Test
public void TestNotThrows() {
  try {
    foo(1);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // uh oh, test failed
    Assert.fail();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to do it like this. It's more verbose, and gives you a less-informative failure than just allowing the exception to propagate out of the test method.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was trying to emphasize `Assert.fail()` as the "thing" that the OP was looking for. But I guess I failed at that.